# Appending additional data to an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use PHP to request data from a MYSQL database. The data i request is song information such as "Artist", "Title", etc...

I would like to append to the results the current time of the server. The reason for this is so that i can calculate when a song ends on the clients machine without having to request two PHP scripts.

Here is the PHP code for the MYSQL data retrieval:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

// open DB connection
require_once("DbConnect.php");

// fetch playlist
$result = $db->query(
    "SELECT `artist`, `title`, `label`, `albumyear`, `date_played`, `duration`, `picture` "
   ."FROM historylist  ORDER BY `date_played` DESC LIMIT 5 ");

// put into array
while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) $list[] = $row;

// encode and send result
echo json_encode ($list);

?>
```

CURRENT REQUEST OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THIS:

NOTE: This is only one COLUMN of data, you will see that i actually request 'DESC LIMIT 5'

*[{"**artist**":"Brothers in Progress & Venditti Bros",

"**title**":"Hacienda Real Project (Jorge TakeiRemix)",

"**label**":"Dantze",

"**albumyear**":"2013",

"**date_played**":"2014-11-24 20:45:28",

"**duration**":"12215",

"**picture**":"az_B111860__Brothers in Progress & Venditti Bros.jpg"}]***

So everything fine here, just a standard request for data.

What i would like to do now is somehow add to the array the server's time in milliseconds.

Is it possible to somehow add to the first result in the array the output from the code below (which is the servers time in milliseconds).

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$serverTime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

echo json_encode($serverTime);
?>
```

Many thanks for taking the time to look through my question, I hope you can help me get the results i am looking for...!

Comment: You want it only in the FIRST result in the array?

Comment: You might want to check out media events. One of them might work out beter for you: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#mediaevents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't embed the time in the json results. That's mixing different data. It's json, just build a structure around it:

```
$data = array();
$data['dbdata'] = $list;
$data['servertime'] = microtime(true);

echo json_ecode($data);
```

Then inyour client, all your DB results are in `data.dbdata`, and `data.servertime` is your timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

The plain answer to your question is, *you can just modify your loop*. See below. But the *correct* answer is the one given by Marc B.

```
// put into array
while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
    // If this is the first row of the result...
    if (empty($list)) {
        $row['ServerTime'] = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    }
    $list[] = $row;
}
```

and it will end up in the first element of the JSON. Or you can do this explicitly (and assuming that there *is* at least one result...)

```
$list[0]['ServerTime'] = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Only be aware that client/server synchronisation is not so straightforward. There will be a slight error due to several causes (JSON transmission time, for one).

A brute implementation of Marc B's answer would be to add the data immediately before output

```
// And one thing I forgot - always best to specify type, and charset.
// Some JS libraries may balk at the output otherwise.
Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');

json_encode(array(
    'ServerTime' => round(microtime(true)*1000),
    'list' => $list
));
```